# How can I implement a method from a class I extend from in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class Abc {
    doTask() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Def extends Abc {   
    // How can I access doTask() here?
}
```

I would like to implement that method doTask() inside of the class Def.  Can someone give me advice on how I can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `super` if you plan to override it e.g. :

```
class Abc {
    doTask() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Def extends Abc {   
    doTask(){
        return super.doTask();
    }
}
```

or just `this` if you don't e.g:

```
class Eef extends Abc {
    foo(){
        return this.doTask();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use this.doTask() in a member of Def.   E.g:

```
class Abc {
    doTask() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Def extends Abc {   
    // How can I access doTask() here?
    likeThis() {
        return this.doTask() + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override it, overload it and use it in the child class equally to the parent one, for instance:

```
class A{

public void dotask(){
//blabla
}
}
Class B extends A{

//overriding
public void dotask(){
}

//overloading
public void dotask(int a){
}

//simple use
public void anotherTask(){
doTask();
}
}
```

Comment: This answer looks a bit like C#!

Comment: wow ! I didn't know I can write c# buddy :) !? could you please specify where it doesn't exactly look like a Java here ?